# Run pig in oozie shell action

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have created a simple pigscript which loads 10 records and stores in a table.

When I invoke this pig(stored in HDFS) file using oozie Shell action,I get and error as follows:

```
>>> Invoking Shell command line now >>
Exit code of the Shell command 5
<<< Invocation of Shell command completed <<<
<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
```

I have put the shell file in the lib folder in the workspace and added all the required jar files in the same lib folder. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Is the PigScript running Properly?

Comment: Checked in server. It is working fine

Comment: Try to check the Logs like stderr,stdout might be helpful

Comment: >>> Invoking Shell command line now >>
Exit code of the Shell command 5
<<< Invocation of Shell command completed <<<
<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

This is the log

Comment: this is stdout logs I guess. Check for stderr also

Comment: They are blank. Both stdout and stderror.
When i have checked the entire logs i have found out the above mentioned errors

Comment: The guy meant **the YARN logs** for the container that ran the Oozie Launcher job. Like in *"running external `job_0000000_0000`"*

Comment: Oozie has a Pig action, that automatically gets the required dependencies from the Oozie "Pig ShareLib" on HDFS. There's a good reason for that.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are running PIG script in shell action ?As @SamsonScharfrichter mentioned oozie has PIG action to do same in much more clean way

Comment: i would like to loop the same workflow multiple times on a particular parameter(date) which i am unable to achieve using pig action.However when i use shell i am unable to invoke pig. Do i need to install any additional packages to make it work?

Comment: can you explain the scenario where you want to call pig script multiple times for the same workflow? If pig script takes a different input each time , you can write multiple workflows

Comment: I want to run pig script for a series of dates say:
Jan 1st,
Jan 3rd,
Jan 5th,

If i give a list of dates, workflow should be able to run for the specified set of dates

Comment: can somebody tell me what I try next?....
I am still trying to fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this this issue by the following steps:

```
1)Created a workflow in hue placing a pig action to invoke pigscript.
2)Generated the workflow.xml file by clicking the run button.
3)Ran the workflow.xml through commandline by adding a shell wrapper class which iterates and gives dates as input parameters.
```

JOB.PROPERTIES file:

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=True
security_enabled=False
dryrun=False
jobTracker=<jobtracker>
nameNode=<nameNode>
oozie.wf.application.path = /user/hue/oozie/workspaces/hue-oozie-1470122057.79/workflow.xml
```

shell file:

```
 for date in 20160101 20160102 20160103
 oozie job -oozie http://<serverip>:11000/oozie -config job.properties run
```